# cloth doesn't work after meta rig

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, sculpting, cloth-simulation

I have a problem when I want to put cloth on character, after I did meta rig.
I put cloth but it doesn't effect anything, except collision with character...even gravity doesn't work.

Comment: You need to parent the cloth as well, or you can use the Data Transfer modifier to transfer the vertex groups, then give it an Armature modifier